# Is a lower bound of the function $f$ required in order to assert: $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty \implies \lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^x f=\infty$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Below is a quick proof of the following statement:

> Suppose $f$ is a continuous function and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty$. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^x f=\infty$.

Consider an arbitrary $M \gt 0$. By assumption there exists an $x_0: \forall x \gt x_0:f(x)\gt M \gt 0.$ Because $f$ is continuous, we know that $f$ is bounded below on $[0,x_0]$, which means that there is an $\alpha: \forall y \in [0,x_0]: f(y) \gt \alpha$. Next, we will partition $\displaystyle\int_0^x f$ into two sections: $\displaystyle \int_0^{x_0}f$ and $\displaystyle\int_{x_0}^{x}f$. It is clear that $\displaystyle \int_0^{x_0}f \geq \alpha\cdot (x_0-0)=\alpha x_0$. In order to ensure that $\displaystyle \int_0^x f \gt M$, we must find an $x'$ such that $\forall x \gt x': \displaystyle\int_{x_0}^{x}f \gt M+|\alpha x_0|.$ Noting that for any  $x \gt x_0$: $\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^x f \geq M\cdot (x-x_0)$, we can solve for $x'$ as follows:

$(x-x_0)M \gt M+|\alpha x_0|  \iff x-x_0 \gt 1+\frac{|\alpha x_0|}{M}\iff x \gt 1+\frac{|\alpha x_0|}{M}+x_0$. As such, if we let $x'= 1+\frac{|\alpha x_0|}{M}+x_0$, then we can be sure that for any $x \gt x': \displaystyle \int_0^x f \gt M$.

---

I think the above proof is correct, but I wondered if the continuity requirement was essential. My argument certainly made use of continuity when I established the lower bound $\alpha$. However, in thinking about the following picture:

[image: Picture 1]

it occurred to me that maybe there was something interesting in the fact that, at some point, the discontinuous sections that involve $f$ approaching $-\infty$ can only take  place across some finite distance $[0,z]$ where $z$ is the point (given by the assumption of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f=\infty$ ) that $f$ must be $\gt 0$ for all $x$ thereafter.

**Is a lower bound of the function required in order to assert:$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty \implies \displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^x f=\infty$**

Comment: For your discontinuous example, you have o arrange $\int_0^a f = -\infty$ for some $a$.  If the improper integral $\int_0^a f$ converges, that cannot happen, even if $f$ is not bounded below.

Comment: @GEdgar maybe I did not pose my question clearly. If all I know is $\lim_{x \to \infty} f=\infty$, can I conclude anything about $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^x f$?

Comment: If you know that $\int_0^x f$ exists (that is, converges) for all $x$, you will be fine.  If $\int_0^x f$ does not exist, then of course you cannot talk about its limit.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason for imposing continuity on $f$ is to ensure that $\int\limits_{0}^{x} f(x) dx $ exists for any $x>0$. If in the question, instead of continuity it had been given that $\int\limits_{0}^{x} f(x) dx$ exists for any $x>0$, the assertion would have been true still.

You could have simply set $M=1$. Then, there exists $x_0$ such that for all $x\geq x_0$, $f(x) > 1$. Simply set $$\int\limits_{0}^{x_0}f(x)dx=A.$$
Then,
$$\int\limits_{0}^{x} f(x) dx > A + (x-x_0)$$
for all $x>x_0$. Clearly, as $x$ increases, the RHS increases and goes to infinity and hence LHS should also.

Let us now see an example, where a lower bound for $f$ does not exist on any interval of the kind $[0,x]$ (and hence $f$ not continuous there), but $\int\limits_{0}^{x} f(x) dx $ exists for any $x$ and $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$. The integral is
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \log x dx,$$
where $\log x$ can be extended to any discontinuous function $f(x)$ on $[0,\infty]$. It is easy to see by integration by parts that
$$\int\limits_{0}^{x} \log x dx= x\log x- x.$$
Clearly the above integral goes to $\infty$ ad $x\to \infty$. Notice also that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$.